# Is there a command line interface for the j programming language?

Tags: installation, language

I wanted to start [learning j](http://www.jsoftware.com/), so I downloaded the `osx_mac_intel 701` version and noticed that the instructions on running `j` is to run the `jhs701`, and follow the link to the webpage where we can interactively play with `j`. I looked through the `bin` directory but could not find a command line tool that did not require the `web` interface. So my question is, is there a commandline tool for j, if not, why not?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's called `jconsole` (or `jconsole.exe` in Windows) and located in the `bin` directory.

Why? Because an interactive shell is useful for learning a programming language and testing code.

And the directions on the site suggests that you read the [J Primer](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/primer/contents.htm), which has a [Get Started](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/primer/get_started.htm) section, which tells you to launch `jconsole` via the J program icon. It doesn't tell you to run `jhs` (J HTTP Server), which is a web server/IDE.

Comment: `jconsole` from the bin directory in the `701` download also does not give me an interactive shell, instead it gives me this `http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3761620/jconsole.png`

Comment: There was a conflict in names of binary that `jconsole` has, therefore it was running the wrong `jconsole`. It works now

Comment: @Doboy: Ah, yea, I also came across the Java jconsole when I was doing my research.